# What is the best way to use ensemble models?

Tags: ensemble-learning

1.Use the model that does the best on its own several times
 2. Use uncorrelated weak kearner models
 3. Use highly corrected, strong learners
 4.  Use only two models at a time

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you want with an example???

Comment: Oh... I am sorry but it is just a question from  test, and I don't have any example .